# How can I save a object from TStringList class to file (Delphi XE 2) with UTF8 without BOM?

Tags: delphi, utf-8, tstringlist

When I save the object from TStringList class file content to a file, the file is saved with UTF-8 correctly but UTF-8 with BOM by default.

My code is:

```
myFile := TStringList.Create;
try
  myFile.Text := myData;
  myFile.saveToFile('myfile.dat', TEncoding.UTF8)
finally
  FreeAndNil(myFile);
end;
```

In the example the file "myfile.dat" appear as "UTF-8 BOM" encoding.

How can I save the file without BOM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply have to set the property [`TStrings.WriteBOM`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStrings.WriteBOM) to `false`.

The documentation tells us about this:

> Will cause SaveToStream or SaveToFile to write a BOM.
>
> Set **WriteBOM** to **True** to cause SaveToStream to write a BOM (byte-order mark) to the stream and to cause SaveToFile to write a BOM to the file.

Comment: Thanks @sir-rufo this really a good exit. But is true with a new file. Is not true when reads a file before save (LoadFromFile...). Maybe problems with Delphi XE2. I will try to update the Delphi version. This is so strange.

Comment: I did not get the point because I did not see any line of code (XE8), where the property `WriteBOM` is set except in `constructor` and `AssignTo` which is as expected. The default value is `true` and will not change unless you do so.

Comment: Just an FYI, `TStrings.WriteBOM` was added in Delphi XE, but `TStrings` first gained `TEncoding` support in D2009. But SirRufo is correct, `WriteBOM` will always be True, even after a load, unless you explicitly set it to False. The `TStrings.LoadFrom...()` methods do not change the value of `WriteBOM`, but they *do* change the value of the `TStrings.Encoding` property.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this by creating your own encoding class descended from `TUTF8Encoding` and overriding the `GetPreamble` method :-

```
type
  TUTF8EncodingNoBOM = class(TUTF8Encoding)
  public
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;
```

function TUTF8EncodingNoBOM.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
end;

Comment: Andy_D In my test, used the class that you modified, the final file is saved in ANSI encoding.

Comment: @FabianoSilva Are you sure? How did you check output encoding?

Comment: Yes @GabrielF, at Notepad++ the output encoding is ANSI.

Comment: @FabianoSilva IIRC, by default, if a file contains no non-ANSI chars, notepad++ identifies it as ANSI (in this case, UTF8 and ANSI are the same thing). Try adding in some special chars before saving or change Notepad++ configuration to identify it as UTF8 w/o BOM (I don't remember where you change that).

Comment: @FabianoSilva I think it's under `Setttings -> Preferences -> New document`. If you choose `Encoding` as `UTF8 w/o BOM` and check `Apply to opened ANSI files`, Notepad++ will identify as UTF8 plain ASCII files.

Comment: @GabrielF the Notepad++ deceived me. Closing and opening the file again made to show the correct encoding. Thanks.